# Q-Divisor and Determinant Map on a Maximal Order

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

Given a smooth projective surface $X$, let $A$ be a sheaf of maximal orders in a division ring.
Let us for simplicity assume $A$ ramifies in one curve $C$ with ramification index $e$. Let $A^*$ be the dual sheaf.

How can I see that the determinant map is a map from $A^*$ to $O_X((1-\frac{1}{e})C)$?
And how to understand the invertible sheaf $O_X((1-\frac{1}{e})C)$? How to handle the rational coefficients?

Since $A$ only ramifies in C, we have that $A$ is Azumaya on $U:=X\backslash C$. So on 
$U$ we have $A^*\cong A$. There the determinant map induces a map $A^{\*} \rightarrow O_U$ since $A$ is just a matrix algbera etale locally. So I see that we have a map $A^* \rightarrow O_X(rC)$. But how to find $r=1-\frac{1}{e}$? How can i determine $A^*$ on $C$?

The question arose reading Theorem 7.1.4. on page 157 of this script: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/courses/711/ordersms-num.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant should map to ${\cal A}^* \rightarrow {\cal O}_X(e(1-1/e)$.  You can see this along $C$ in codimension one since if you \'etale localize at the generic point of $C$ then the structure Theorem for maximal orders says that ${\cal A}$ localizes to something Morita
equivalent to

R tR ...  tR

R  R  ... tR

... ... ...

R ...   R tR

R ... ...  R

with equal size blocks.  Where $R$ is the strictly henselian d.v.r at the generic point of $C$.  Now if you if you dualize and count $t^{-1}$, you can have at most a pole of order $e-1$
in the determinant.

Comment: Thanks. This looks better. I get the dual of the module you specified by transposing and then replace the $t$'s by $t^{-1}$? Then taking the determinant gives a polynomial in $t^{-1}$ with the desired pole order. So one does not need $\mathbb{Q}$-divisors at all, very good!